# Is there a way to determine the number of subgroups (with size $s$) while computing $A^b \bmod P$? Constructing a $P$ with $n$ times size $s$?

Tags: discrete-logarithm

If you compute $A^b \bmod P$ for all $b$ the set of results $R$ depend at $A$ (and $P$).

$R = \{A^b \bmod P, \forall \space b \in \mathbb{N}\}$

In case $R$ contain all numbers from 1 to $P-1$, it has the size $s = |R| = P-1$ then $A$ is a prime root of $P$. In all other cases size $s < P-1$.

1. Can you determine how many $A$'s with subgroup size $s$ a certain $P$ has?
2. Can you construct a $P$ which has $n$ $A$'s with size $s$?
3. Is there a max number of $A$'s with the same size $s$ (independent of size $P$)?
4. Does 1-3.) change if you add the condition A need to be a prime as well?

---

I did some testing. I noticed the size of $s$ is a product of some prime factors of $P-1$.

E.g. $109619 = 2*23*2383+1$

With Primes as possible $A$'s the numbers $1601, 13619, 17321, 36833, 104473$ generate a subgroup of size $s=46=2*23$

So far I got not more than 5 $A$'s which a prime as well for any $P$ I tested. Is that a max number or is my $P$ just too small?

Comment: I suggest you study some elementary group theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.Can you determine how many $A$'s with subgroup size $s$ a certain $P$ has?

If $s$ is a divisor of $P-1$, then there will be precisely $\phi(s)$ elements with that has order $s$ (assuming the convention that $\phi(1) = 1$); otherwise, there will be 0 elements with that order.

> 2.Can you construct a $p$ which has $n$ $A$'s with size $s$?

If $n = \phi(s)$, then you need to find any prime $p$ of the form $p = ks+1$ (for an integer $k$), that is, a prime $p$ with $p \equiv 1 \pmod{s}$.  If $n \ne \phi(s)$, then, no, you cannot.

> 3.Is there a max number of $A$'s with the same size (independent of size $P$)?

No, it is unbounded.

> 4.Does 1-3.) change if you add the condition A need to be a prime as well?

1 and 2 does; however it's unclear how - values from the group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ which just happen to have the same representation as primes in $\mathbb{N}$ isn't a particularly clean condition.

3 does not; if we consider an arbitrary large safe prime $p$ [1], then we have $(p-1)/2$ elements of order $p-1$ and of the order $(p-1)/2$; every integer (hence every prime) between 2 and $p-2$ are in one of those two groups, and hence (by making $p$ arbitrarily large), we can make one of those two groups contain an arbitrarily large set of primes.

---

[1] There's no proof that there exist arbitrarily large safe primes, but it is almost certainly true

Comment: Thanks for fast response, especially for the relation between $\phi(s)$ and the count. Will have some trials. @4.3. But with increasing $P$ also the group size $s$ increases. So they are not independent in that case. But you can make it as big you like, so it should work.

Comment: Something wrong here. I did some testing. E.g. number $P=403617=( 3    *19 *   73*    97)$ and $P-1 = 32*12613=2^5*12613$. If I pick $s=32$ as a divisor of $P-1$ then $\phi(s=32)=16$ elements should exist with order $s$ (poncho's answer for case 1.). In test I found 60 numbers (instead of 16) with order $s$, so 60 numbers with $number^{32} = 1 \mod p$. (with 16 in exponent they are not 1, all of them are 162280). Some numbers:  8093,     8969,  22193,  28387,  41077       47387, 54833,    61561, 71249,  80447,   83563,  91199, 91807, 95191

Comment: @J.Doe: the rule I gave assumed $P$ was prime; if it's not, then $\mathbb{Z}_P^*$ is not a cyclic group (and certainly not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{P-1}$), with a considerably more complex structure, and so it doesn't hold